# php submit variable outside form?

Tags: php, forms, function

so, i am trying to create a php page that does this: when i click a button i get a random number from 1 to 6, and then i created a form with an input where i am asked to type in the number and then send it to a database, the problem is that i also want to save the random number shown before, and here is where i am stuck, i have no idea on how to proceed, here is the code i have:
the file is named Main.php, i haven't put a submit button on the form yet since i am stressing on this problem

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
    
<form action="Main.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="rolldice" value="Roll the dice" />
</form>

Your number:

<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" and isset($_POST['rolldice'])) roll();
    function roll() {$num = rand(1,6); echo($num);}
?>



<form action="insert.php" method="POST">
    <label> Number on the dice </label>
    <input type="text" name="declared" value="<?php echo $declared;?>">
</form>
    

</html>
```

Comment: what is `$declared` ?

Comment: (1) if you're going to do this in PHP, use GET, not POST. You're not posting data to the server for remote storage, you're only asking it to generate data. However, (2) I'd strongly recommend not doing this in PHP at all. Rolling a die should not require reloading a page in the slightest, that's something you can do entirely client side using normal JS (and modern JS: no using `onclick` with javascript-in-a-string attributes).

Comment: oh, i used $num for the number shown by the dice while $declared for then number i will then declare in the form.

Comment: the reason i am using php is because i heard it was the best programming language to create a website with, also i am using xampp as a virtual server.

Comment: The difference between doing it in JS (client side) and PHP (server side) is that JS won't need to make any request to the server. JS lives on the client, while PHP requires a request to the server. If you can do what you want without calling the server, that's better (decreases the load on your server and will be faster)